# C++ How can I remove pointers refering to the same element in two different std::lists?

Tags: c++, pointers, c++11, runtime-error, stdlist

I am new in programming c++, so please don't be angry with me if my source code is not exactly brilliant.

I have to write a programm to handle with nodes and edges in a graph for my studies.

I have 2 `std::lists` in my source code. The first one is to store general `Nodes` and the other one for saving the kind class of my nodes called `ArticleNodes`. In general, all elements are pointers to the created objects.

To figure out whether one object is the same in the other list I save the memory address and compare it to the elements on the second list. If there is a match the second element will be deleted.

Now I'd like to delete one element in both lists:

```
void Graph::deleteNode(unsigned int nodeNumber)
{
    list<Node*>::iterator it = m_nodes.begin();
    ArticleNode* pCurrentArticleNode;
    for(unsigned int i=1; i<nodeNumber; i++) { it++; }

    Node* pCurrentNode = (*it);

    for (list<ArticleNode*>::iterator itArticle = m_articlenode.begin(); itArticle != m_articlenode.end(); itArticle++)
    {
        pCurrentArticleNode = (*itArticle);
        if(pCurrentNode==pCurrentArticleNode) { m_articlenode.remove(pCurrentArticleNode); }
    }

    m_nodes.remove(pCurrentNode);

    delete pCurrentNode;
    delete pCurrentArticleNode;
}
```

I can compile this, but when I call the function, my programm just exits with return 1.
Actually, I figured out that the remove-command in the if-clause is the problem. Why does that not work??

Comment: If both pCurrentNode and pCurrentArticleNode point to the same object, then deleting one will remove the object, leaving nothing where the object used to be, and then deleting the other one will remove the object again, creating an anti-object where an empty place existed a moment ago. Anti-objects will annihilate violently on contact with objects, and the resulting gamma rays will erase your hard disk and may permanently damage your CPU. Or at least this *could* happen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use algorithms more than doing everything manually:

```
void Graph::deleteNode(unsigned int nodeNumber)
{
    assert (nodeNumber < m_nodes.size());

    auto it = std::next( m_nodes.begin(), nodeNumber - 1 );

    auto itArticle = std::find( m_articlenode.begin(), m_articlenode.end(), *it );
    if( itArticle != m_articlenode.end() )
        m_articlenode.erase( itArticle );

    delete *it;
    m_nodes.erase(it);
}
```

Btw your code deletes the same object twice.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That works correctly for me :)
But why does my code deletes the same object twice? I thought that i delete the object and then the pointer in the other list to that memory adress.. But i know. I have a lot to learn!

Comment: @user5223762 `pCurrentNode==pCurrentArticleNode` simply means that 2 pointers point to the same object. Actually your code did not delete the same object twice due to bug in your code (missing break in the loop) but would when you fix the first issue

Comment: @Slava, But do we know that ArticleNode is a node?

Comment: @WernerErasmus how OP checked object type when populated `m_articlenode` container is outside of scope of this question. I can only assume it is done correctly, with that in mind if 2 pointers are equal - they point to the same object.

Comment: @Slava. What would next do if nodeNumber is out of range?

Comment: @WernerErasmus OP's code assumed that it is not out of range, otherwise his code would have UB. The same for `std::next()` I just followed his logic assuming he keeps that invariant.

Comment: @Slava. The OP deleted node twice. I would not make those assumptions about keeping invariants, seeing that he has stated that he is green.

Comment: @WernerErasmus error handling is pretty complex topic, I do not think printing diagnostics to `std::cout` solves the issue. I am adding comment to notify OP though

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86905/discussion-between-werner-erasmus-and-slava).

Comment: @WernerErasmus unfortunately chat is not accessible for me, sorry.

Comment: Okay. My thought was this: I have an object with the type of `ArticleNode`. That is a kindclass of `Node`.
When i delete the object through the remove() command in the m_node list then i just left a pointer in the other list, which refers to the memory adress where nothing sensefull is stored. Therefore i thought that i could remove this left pointer with the remove() command.

Comment: @user5223762 your logic is fine, you just should not try to `delete` it twice through 2 pointers. And use terms more accurate to avoid confusing, you do not `delete` object when use `remove()` method, you just remove pointer from that container.

Answer (score 1):

When you remove an element from `std::list` object with `remove( )` method, all iterators pointing to that elements become invalid. In your case, after you remove an element from the list `m_articlenode`, the iterator object `itArticle` becomes invalid. And when you increment that iterator, you get an undefined behavior.

Pay attention that the method `remove( )` deletes all of the items in the list with given value. So you don't need the for-loop at all. Here is the fixed version of your function:

```
void Graph::deleteNode(unsigned int nodeNumber)
{
    list<Node*>::iterator it = m_nodes.begin();
    for(unsigned int i=1; i<nodeNumber; i++) { it++; }

    Node* pCurrentNode = (*it);

    m_articlenode.remove(pCurrentNode);
    m_nodes.remove(pCurrentNode);

    delete pCurrentNode;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the `erase` method of `std::list` in order to remove an element from your list while iterating over it.

This should do the trick:

```cpp
void Graph::deleteNode(unsigned int nodeNumber)
{
  list<Node*>::iterator it = m_nodes.begin();
  ArticleNode* pCurrentArticleNode;
  for(unsigned int i=1; i<nodeNumber; i++) { it++; }

  Node* pCurrentNode = (*it);
  list<ArticleNode*>::iterator itArticle = m_articlenode.begin();

  while(itArticle != m_articlenode.end()) {
    pCurrentArticleNode = (*itArticle);
    if(pCurrentNode==pCurrentArticleNode) {
      m_articlenode.erase(itArticle++);
    } else {
      itArticle++;
    }
  }

  m_nodes.remove(pCurrentNode);

  delete pCurrentNode;
  delete pCurrentArticleNode;
}
```

Comment: That worked on the first moment correct, but after i run that function there is strange behavior with my objects. For example one element's name changend into a misterious name.. I dont' know why. And if i run it twice it will crash. But thank you very much! I think thats the fault of my code in general.

Answer (score 0):

Simple issue in your code is that if you go into the if condition is met and it's body executed, you should come out of the loop. std::remove invalidates the iterator ann you will get issues in next iteration so do:

```
for (list<ArticleNode*>::iterator itArticle = m_articlenode.begin(); itArticle != m_articlenode.end(); itArticle++)
    {
        pCurrentArticleNode = (*itArticle);
        if(pCurrentNode==pCurrentArticleNode) 
        { 
             m_articlenode.remove(pCurrentArticleNode);
             break;
        }
    }
```

In general, there are other issues in the code. As a first step I would suggest using shared_ptr for managing your Nodes and have list of shared_ptr instead of list of pointers.

Answer (score 0):

> I am new in programming c++, so please don't be angry with me if my
>   source code is not exactly brilliant.

We all start somewhere.

> Now I'd like to delete one element in both lists:

OK. Quick question. Why are you deleting article node if it is already deleted (via base Node)? I'm assuming for now node is not duplicated in the list:

My solution below... I've passed the lists as arguments. See comments:

```
#include <list>
#include <algorithm>

struct Node
{
  virtual ~Node(){} //For dyna cast to work...
};

struct ArticleNode : Node
{
};

void deleteNode(std::list<ArticleNode*>& articleList, std::list<Node*>& m_nodes, unsigned int nodeNumber)
{
    using namespace std;

    if (m_nodes.size() > nodeNumber)
    {
      auto it = m_nodes.begin();
      // Advance advances our iterator by N. No need for your for loop - less risk...
      std::advance(it,nodeNumber);
      Node* currentNode = *it;

      //Casting is bad here, but hey, lets assume if type is wrong, we only erase
      // it from Node...(Your call)?
      ArticleNode* currentArticleNode = dynamic_cast<ArticleNode*>(currentNode); 

      if (currentArticleNode) 
      {
        //Use find here.... KISS
        auto foundPos = std::find(articleList.begin(), articleList.end(), currentArticleNode);
        if (foundPos != articleList.end())
        {
          //No need to delete currentArticleNode, as we're deleting it already...
          articleList.erase(foundPos);
        }
        //Assuming only one item for now...
      }
      //Else our node was obviously not the right type, and cannot exist in articleNodes...

      m_nodes.erase(it);
      delete currentNode;
    }
    else
    {
      std::cout << "No such node: " << nodeNumber << std::endl;
    }
}
```